# How to create expandable dynamic linear list and expandable grid list in a same widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create 2 list type data
first linear and other grid type list

now requirement is that both data list height will be dynamic means it should be expand when , new object is added.
and sorting scrollable along with all 4 widgets(sort, list, sort, grid).

like below image:

[image]

i have tried but height is static ,
i have used expanded but not giving result as i'm expecting.

code:

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                 sort(context),//sort widget
                  createForlderView(context), //dynamic list widget
                   sort(context), //sort widget
                  _createGridView()// dynamic grid list widget
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );

Widget sort(BuildContext context){
return  Container(
                    // color: Colors.red,
                    height: 25,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("Folder"),
                        Container(
                          // color:Colors.green,
                          width: 60,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text("Sort"),
                              // SizedBox(width:5),
                              InkWell(onTap: () {}, child: Icon(Icons.sort))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
}

// list view:

Widget createForlderView(BuildContext context) {
    final _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: _height / 1.2,
        child: ListView.builder(
            // padding: ,
            itemCount: directoryItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                leading: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  child: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.brown),
                ),
                title: Text(directoryItems[index]),
                subtitle: Text("15 items"),
                trailing:
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
              ));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

// grid view:
Widget _createGridView() {
    var mSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    /*24 is for notification bar on Android*/
    final double itemHeight = (mSize.height - kToolbarHeight) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = mSize.width / 2;
    int gridItemCount =
        Provider.of<DocumentProvider>(context).allDocuments.length;

    

    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: GridView.count(
          key: animatedListKey,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical, //default
          reverse: false,
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
          children: List.generate(gridItemCount, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: SelectCard(
                index: index,
                itemHeight: itemHeight,
                itemWidth: itemWidth,
                deletefun: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  DeleteDialog(
                      index: index,
                      dateTime:
                          Provider.of<DocumentProvider>(context, listen: false)
                              .allDocuments[index]
                              .dateTime);
                },
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

output screen:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add more Code, or tell what are the parents widget of Expanded widget in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my solution,
used `CustomScrollView` along with it's `slivers:` `SliverToBoxAdapter` (for single widget),`SliverFixedExtentList` (for linear list) , and `SliverGrid` (for Grid list).

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpandableList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<FolderModel> listData;
   final List<FilesModel> gridListData;

  const ExpandableList({Key key, this.listData, this.gridListData}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ExpandableListState createState() => _ExpandableListState();
}

class _ExpandableListState extends State<ExpandableList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          buildAppBar(),
         sorting(title: "folders", tralingTitle: "sort", onTap: (){}),
         expandableListBuilder(),
        
         sorting(title: "files", tralingTitle: "sort",onTap: (){}),
          expandableGridList(),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
  buildAppBar(){
    return SliverAppBar(
      title: Text("Multi Expandable list example"),
      centerTitle: true,
      pinned: true,
    );
  }
  
  expandableListBuilder(){
    return SliverFixedExtentList(
      itemExtent: 75.0,
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                child: Icon(Icons.folder, color: Colors.brown),
              ),
              title: Text(widget.listData[index].title),
              subtitle: Text(widget.listData[index].subtitle),
              trailing:
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert), onPressed: () {}),
            ));
        },
        childCount: widget.listData.length
      ),
    );
  }
  expandableGridList(){
    return SliverGrid(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
      ),
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
        (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 8,
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              child: Text("${widget.gridListData[index].title}${(index+1).toString()}"),
            ),
          );
        },
        childCount: widget.gridListData.length,
      ),
    );
  }

  sorting({String title,String tralingTitle,  void Function() onTap}){
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: 50,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Text(title),
            Container(
              // color:Colors.green,
              width: 60,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(tralingTitle),
                  // SizedBox(width:5),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap:onTap,
                     child: Icon(Icons.sort))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

result:

[image]